# Examples of using GANs to sort numbers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, gan

Does anyone know of any publicly available GAN implementations to sort numbers with? As in, the input to the generator is an unordered sequence of numbers, and the goal of the generator is to output that sequence in its correct (ascending) order.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07475.pdf) claims to have done it, but sadly I do not think they have released their code.